# How to send name and status of job to a text file

Tags: slurm

I am currently using Slurm to run certain jobs and am trying to send the job ID, name, and status of the job to a text file. I have no idea how to go about this. Is this even possible? Sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Do you want to do it at launch time? Or when they are running?

Comment: When they are running

Comment: So you want a command that you can run when jobs are running to print it to a file ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see Id, name and status of running or queued jobs, you can run :

`squeue -u your_user_name`

If you want it to be printed in a file, you can do:

`squeue -u your_user_name > file.txt`

For completed jobs, you can run

`saact`

or

`sacct --starttime "$(date --date="-30 day" +%Y-%m-%d)"`

To get in this example only the jobs run in the last 30 days. As for `squeue`, the output can be redirected to a file using `> file.txt`

Comment: That would be good, but the squeue command doesn't show completed jobs. Is there a way to show completed jobs?